# Is there any simple way of finding the current working directory? c++

Tags: c++, directory

Right, i'm looking for a simple way of finding the working directory path for c++. At the momement i have been unsuccessful.

Comment: On what platform?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path Edit : Fixed link to standard version.

Comment: `getcwd()` on Unix.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++ 17, you should use [std::filesystem::current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path). If you are not, you are stuck with platform-dependent solutions, C++ pre-17 had not notion of a directory at all.

Comment: i used the example program from that link but i get the error 'error: 'filesystem' is not a namespace-name'. i am running c++ 17.12 so i dont see why it wont work

Comment: @Ginger give us the full code and we will tell you what the error is. Please also ask a **separate** question for this, do not vandalize your own question by completely changing it's semantic.

Comment: When you say that you use c++ 17.12 do you mean that you use Code::Blocks 17.12 by any chance?

Comment: @TadeuszA.Kadłubowski brilliant. I didn't even think of it. I thought, C++ 17 is it, and 12 is just a random typo.

Comment: it is the same question?? you put a link in your answer and the example that is in that link errors when i use it with the error i specified.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you are running c++ 17.12? Do you know which version of which brand of a C++ compiler you use?

Comment: yeh thats it sorry. I downloaded it about 2 days ago so i assume so.